# Bootstrap do not work properly outside the index funcion in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Index function works fine, any other does not show bootstrap effects. I think I have seen all the topics about it here and i cant find any solution.

[image: function index()]

[image: any other]

Controller:

```
<?php
class Certyfikat extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->view('/templates/header');
        }
    function index()
    {

    }
    function nowy()
    {
        $this->load->view('/certyfikat/dodaj_nowy');
    }
}
```

View header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: show;
    background-color: #333333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

a.button {
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 70px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0,4s;
}

a.button:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
</head>

<body class="main">

<ul>
  <li><a class="button" href="/home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="button" href="/certyfikat">Certyfikaty</a></li>
  <li><a class="button" href="/category_create">cr</a></li>
</ul>
   <?php $this->load->view('/templates/alrets'); ?>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js");  ?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

View dodaj_nowy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
        <title>My Blog</title>

</head>
<body>

        <h1>Welcome to my Blog!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Comment: even single view do not work properly

Comment: remove first / `$this->load->view('certyfikat/dodaj_nowy'); `

Comment: Make sure you have set your base url in config.php

Comment: I had space bar in 'base url'... Now everything works. Thank you very much for help! :)

Comment: I would not put view in construct area follow the user guide

Comment: I'm learning all the time in my free time, why its not good to put it that way?

Comment: put it in index() not in constructor - index() method is the default one in CI.